# How can I improve the performance of this query?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I've tried to add an index on `records.status`, but the cardinality is so low (<5 unique values) a seq scan was still used.

The query:

```
select distinct "events".* from "events" 
inner join (select "records".* from "records" where "status" = 'Mined') as "record" on "record"."guid" = CAST("events"."return_values"#>>'{guid}' AS text) 
where "events"."status" = 'Waiting' and "event" in ('RecordUpdated', 'RecordDiscovery', 'RecordRetrieval') 
order by "block_number" asc, "transaction_index" asc, "transaction_hash" asc, "log_index" asc 
limit 100;
```

The execution plan looks like:

```
 Limit  (cost=122673.00..122677.25 rows=100 width=1639) (actual time=575.631..575.632 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=122673.00..124045.11 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=548.071..548.071 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=122673.00..122753.71 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=548.068..548.069 rows=0 loops=1)
               Sort Key: events.block_number, events.transaction_index, events.transaction_hash, events.log_index, events.event_id, events.block_hash, events.address, events.return_values, events.event, events.signature, events.raw, events.processing_error, events.confirmations, events.created_at, events.updated_at, events.id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Gather  (cost=47192.22..97302.09 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=548.048..571.664 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=46192.22..93073.59 rows=13452 width=1639) (actual time=526.239..526.241 rows=0 loops=3)
                           Hash Cond: ((events.return_values #>> '{guid}'::text[]) = (records.guid)::text)
                           ->  Parallel Index Scan using events_status_index on events  (cost=0.43..46843.84 rows=13804 width=1639) (actual time=0.106..36.976 rows=16870 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: (status = 'Waiting'::event_status)
                                 Filter: ((event)::text = ANY ('{RecordUpdated,RecordDiscovery,RecordRetrieval}'::text[]))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=42957.65..42957.65 rows=258731 width=44) (actual time=462.763..462.764 rows=205834 loops=3)
                                 Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 56672kB
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on records  (cost=0.00..42957.65 rows=258731 width=44) (actual time=16.322..244.807 rows=205834 loops=3)
                                       Filter: (status = 'Mined'::record_status)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 6625
 Planning Time: 0.432 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 50
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 8.788 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.711 ms, Emission 71.684 ms, Total 84.183 ms
 Execution Time: 602.684 ms
(25 rows)
```

events table:

```
                                          Table "public.events"
      Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 event_id          | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 log_index         | integer                  |           | not null |
 transaction_index | integer                  |           | not null |
 transaction_hash  | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 block_hash        | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 block_number      | integer                  |           | not null |
 address           | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 return_values     | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 event             | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 signature         | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 raw               | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 status            | event_status             |           | not null |
 processing_error  | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 confirmations     | integer                  |           | not null |
 created_at        | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 updated_at        | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 id                | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "events_block_log" btree (block_number, log_index)
    "events_status_index" btree (status)
```

records table:

```
                            Table "public.records"
      Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 guid             | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 data_hash        | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 transaction_hash | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 url              | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 status           | record_status            |           | not null |
 created_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 updated_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 client_id        | character varying(64)    |           | not null |
 event_id         | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 user_id          | character varying(255)   |           |          |
Indexes:
    "records_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (guid)
    "records_client_id_index" btree (client_id)
    "records_event_id_index" btree (event_id)
    "records_user_id_index" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "records_client_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "discoveries" CONSTRAINT "discoveries_record_guid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (record_guid) REFERENCES records(guid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "record_dependencies" CONSTRAINT "record_dependencies_record_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (record) REFERENCES records(guid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "retrievals" CONSTRAINT "retrievals_record_guid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (record_guid) REFERENCES records(guid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

**Edit based on comments:**

Here are the results of turning off seq_scans and io timing on

```
 Limit  (cost=149630.09..149634.34 rows=100 width=1639) (actual time=547.957..547.957 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=225599
   ->  Unique  (cost=149630.09..151002.20 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=526.203..526.204 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=225599
         ->  Sort  (cost=149630.09..149710.80 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=526.192..526.193 rows=0 loops=1)
               Sort Key: events.block_number, events.transaction_index, events.transaction_hash, events.log_index, events.event_id, events.block_hash, events.address, events.return_values, events.event, events.signature, events.raw, events.processing_error, events.confirmations, events.created_at, events.updated_at, events.id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Buffers: shared hit=225599
               ->  Gather  (cost=1000.86..124259.17 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=526.164..545.039 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     Buffers: shared hit=225599
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..120030.67 rows=13452 width=1639) (actual time=505.207..505.208 rows=0 loops=3)
                           Buffers: shared hit=225599
                           ->  Parallel Index Scan using events_status_index on events  (cost=0.43..46843.84 rows=13804 width=1639) (actual time=12.540..58.632 rows=17030 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: (status = 'Waiting'::event_status)
                                 Filter: ((event)::text = ANY ('{RecordUpdated,RecordDiscovery,RecordRetrieval}'::text[]))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                 Buffers: shared hit=21233
                           ->  Index Scan using records_pkey on records  (cost=0.43..5.30 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=51091)
                                 Index Cond: ((guid)::text = (events.return_values #>> '{guid}'::text[]))
                                 Filter: (status = 'Mined'::record_status)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                 Buffers: shared hit=204366
 Planning Time: 0.410 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 41
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 7.868 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.929 ms, Emission 55.472 ms, Total 66.269 ms
 Execution Time: 570.247 ms
```

Comment: I think that is pretty good for a query like that.

Comment: JIT is likely to be slowing you down more than speeding you up.  Try turning that off.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Using the primary key index on "record" might be better than the hash join.  What happens if you do `set enable_seqscan = off` before running the query?  Please do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  And turn track_io_timing to on first if you can.

Comment: @jjanes It is run pretty often so faster is better. I added the results of your suggestions to the OP

Comment: It is not clear to me that you are going to get much faster than one of the two plans you already have.  You could still turn off JIT, and maybe get more parallel workers to be thrown at it, if you have enough CPUs to warrant that.

Comment: Using WHERE EXISTS() instead of a JOIN so you can get rid of DISTINCT is one option since you are not returning anything from the joined table.

Answer (score 2):

Using WHERE EXISTS() with a correlated suqeuery instead of a JOIN is one option since you are not returning anything from the joined table.

Something like (untested):

```
select "events".* 
from "events" 
WHERE exists (select 1 from "records" 
              where "record"."status" = 'Mined')  
              AND "record"."guid" = CAST("events"."return_values"#>>'{guid}' AS text)) 
      AND "events"."status" = 'Waiting' 
      AND "events"."event" in ('RecordUpdated', 'RecordDiscovery', 'RecordRetrieval') 
order by "block_number" asc, "transaction_index" asc, "transaction_hash" asc, "log_index" asc 
limit 100;
```

You can also add an index on the JSONB field for the key you are linking on.

Comment: NB In Postgres you don’t need to select a column in an `exists` clause! Simply write `… exists (select from …`

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* need that "distinct" on the top level **select**?

This is *always* a Red Flag to me, too-often added as a "quick and easy" way to "get rid" of "duplicate" rows that appear in the result set "for some reason".

Even worse ...

```
select distinct events.* ...
```

... has to perform that de-duplication across *all* the columns in the table.  I'm guessing there are "a lot", which is why you chose to use "*" (which, BTW, you *never* should in Production code) and that could make for a *lot* of work from your database.

Your query is only ordered by *four* fields, but just check out the **Sort Key** in the Execution Plan (reformatted for emphasis):

```
Sort  (cost=149630.09..149710.80 rows=32285 width=1639) (actual time=526.192..526.193 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: events.block_number
           , events.transaction_index
           , events.transaction_hash
           , events.log_index
           , events.event_id
           , events.block_hash
           , events.address
           , events.return_values
           , events.event
           , events.signature
           , events.raw
           , events.processing_error
           , events.confirmations
           , events.created_at
           , events.updated_at
           , events.id
```

DISTINCT at its sneakiest worst!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i see is the GUID are text which is the slowest and widest storage method for this type.

See if the GUID can be converted to [Postgresql UUID type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) which turns them  into Integer type.  Its faster and uses almost half as much space for the index and space for those columns.